# How to add function to object?

Tags: angular, angular7

I have object:

```
  public functions = {
    chosenYearHandler: null,
    chosenMonthHandler: null
  };
```

And there is method:

```
  public chosenMonthHandler(normalizedYear: any) {
    this.form.controls["date"].setValue(normalizedYear);
  }
```

I fill method to object like:

```
this.functions.chosenMonthHandler = this.chosenMonthHandler;
```

Then in template I tried to call method like:

```
   (monthSelected)="functions.chosenMonthHandler($event, dp)"
```

It says:

```
FilterMobileComponent.html:420 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'chosenYearHandler' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent]
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: But why you want to do like this ? this can be done easily by creating generic method

Comment: Could you write generic solution?

Comment: @OPV please produce stackblitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try defined your function using "flat arrow" like

```
chosenMonthHandler= (normalizedYear: any) => {
   this.form.controls["date"].setValue(normalizedYear);
}
```

So, "this" will be the component (I just find a good [explanation](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html) about flat arrow functions)